# How to save following screenshot to mysql database with Php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

[this is Screenshot of my csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFQvP.png)

[image]

I want to save this csv file in mysql db with php

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Well, Parse the CSV File, then store in your tables

Comment: actually i m very new in this can u send some sample code.Thnx in advance

Comment: Here's the quick way, [Parse like this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and then just [insert](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Research, try something, add your code & point your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> if (isset($_POST['submit']))
>
> {
>
> ```
>    $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
>    $type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
>    $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
>    $config['upload_path'] = 'upload';
>    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
>             if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
>                 #error in file uploading
>             } else {
>                 $data_array = array("Employee_name" =>  
>                    "file_name" => $file_name,   
>                 );
>                 #Pass data to model
>                 $this->UserModel->insertData($data_array);
>             }
>  }
> ```